# How Do I use Having and group By clause in hibernate?

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, criteria

I have a sql Query which is something like this.

```
SELECT VERSION_ID FROM VIEWTEST
where ( item_id='I001' and value ='V001')
or  ( item_id='I002' and value ='V002')
or ( item_id= 'I003'and value ='V003')
group by VERSION_ID
having count(1) = 3
```

My ViewTest entity is something like this.

```
@Column(name = "version_id")
    private String versionId;

@Column(name = "item_id")
    private String itemId;

@Column(name = "value")
    private String  value;
```

Here is the Crieteria Query written by me.

```
 CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder();
         CriteriaQuery<String> query = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(String.class);
         Root<ViewTest> testRoot = query.from(ViewTest.class);
         List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
         Predicate p1 = criteriaBuilder.equal(testRoot.get("itemId"), "I001");
         Predicate p2 = criteriaBuilder.equal(testRoot.get("itemId"), "I002");
         Predicate p3 = criteriaBuilder.equal(testRoot.get("itemId"), "I003");

         Predicate v1 = criteriaBuilder.equal(testRoot.get("value"), "V001");
         Predicate v2 = criteriaBuilder.equal(testRoot.get("value"), "V002");
         Predicate v3 = criteriaBuilder.equal(testRoot.get("value"), "V003");
         predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(p1 , v1));
         predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(p2 , v2));
         predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.and(p3 , v3));
```

Now I dont know how to add group By and Having clause to this criteria.

Can someone please help me out?

Found a better way to do it.

just added below to my code.

```
query.groupBy(testRoot.<String> get("versionId"));
query.having(criteriaBuilder.in(criteriaBuilder.count(testRoot.get("versionId"))).value(
        queryCount));
```

this did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Projections?
[Hibernate developer guide: Projections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html_single/#querycriteria-projection)

Example:

```
List results = session.createCriteria(Cat.class)
.setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
    .add( Projections.rowCount() )
    .add( Projections.avg("weight") )
    .add( Projections.max("weight") )
    .add( Projections.groupProperty("color") )
)
.list();
```